# automatic refresh of only specific <div> element of a page in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to refresh content of particular  element instead of whole page, after some interval using Jquery?

When I used code shown below, its only appending same data several times after defined time duration, but I don't want this, I want only that data should be append if any new data inserted by user in mysql.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"confess_show.php",
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data){
            $('.content').append(data);
        }
    });
}, 6000);
```

Comment: how are you tracking what is new vs already delivered to page?

Comment: You probably want to write more logic in your `success` callback. Orion's answer leads the way. You almost certainly want to keep a reference to the last unique identifier of your data and either send it to `confess_show.php` as paramter so response will only contain new data or write some code `success` to use `$.append` only for newer data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a timestamp, as it doesn't need to get latest insert id of every update.

```
var timestamp = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"confess_show.php?t=" + timestamp,
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data){
            if(data != ''){ //Only append data if there are some new
                timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); //Set timestamp to current time
                $('.content').append(data);
            }
        }
    });
}, 6000);
```

confess_show.php should then only fetch rows with a timestamp larger than $_GET['t']. That way, you don't need to keep track of the latest id shown.

Comment: thanks elias.. it is what i wanted. idea of timestamp didn't stuck in my mind

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:-

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load('response.php');
      //OR THIS WAY : $("#responsecontainer").load('response.php?randval='+ Math.random());

   }, 5000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="responsecontainer"></div>
```

Create a file "response.php" and add php script there, it'll load that php code after every 5seconds(5000 = 5seconds)

Answer (score 1):

change the line:

```
$('.content').append(data);
```

to

```
$('.content').html(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want `append`, but NOT `replace`.

So if in this case, you should remember where you go off.

I just make an example:

```
// remember the last id fetched.
var last_id = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        // here, send the last_id, and only fetch data newer than that.
        url: "confess_show.php?newer_than="+last_id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            // also, here, after data was fetched, update the last_id with the latest one.
            last_id = getLastId(data);
            $('.content').append(data);
        }
    });
}, 6000);
```

Comment: op should better vote you up or what?. Also, s/he makes it very clear that s/he doesn't have enough rep yet to upvote

Answer (score 1):

May be something like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"confess_show.php",
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data){
            if($('#yourDataWrapperId').length == 0){ //check if data exist
                $('.content').append(data);
            }
        }
    });
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Maybe not he wanted, he said 'if any new data inserted' that means the keypoint is do not show the same row more than once.

Comment: maybe a set of row, but most probably have replicated rows.